# iDangerous Swiper 2 : Changing CSS/Style of Arrows on First & Last Slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I'm *strictly* working with an older version of **Swiper (v2.7.6)** and also **jQuery (v1.10.1)**

I'm trying to change the opacity of the left and right arrows when the first or last slide is active. (Left-arrow will be lower opacity if on 1st slide, and same with the right-arrow if on last slide.

Arrows will return to full opacity if in-between slides.
Unfortunately after many hours I couldn't resolve this.

Here is my current jQuery code:

```
if ($(".swiper-slide:eq(0)").hasClass("swiper-slide-active")) {
  $(".arrow-left").css("opacity","0.2");
}
else {
  $(".arrow-left").css("opacity","1");
}
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <a class="arrow-left" href="#"></a> 
  <a class="arrow-right" href="#"></a>

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

API doc for Swiper 2 can be found [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/Swiper2/API.md).

Thank you.

Comment: Have javascript/jQuery count your slides, and compare the current shown one to that number. Once you're at the First/Last, changing the opacity would not be a problem for you as I see from your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think Swiper already handle this for you, just specify the html element that contains the arrows when you create  swiper instance

```
(function () {
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    nextButton: '.arrow-right',
    prevButton: '.arrow-left',
    ...

}); 
})(jQuery);
```